# Can't apply custom css to TinyMCE <a> tags

Tags: css, tinymce

I'm loading a custom css file with plenty of changes that are being applied to the formats menu options. However, anything with the "a." selector and "table." selector in my custom css file does not work.

It shows in the menu but it isn't clickable. I can see that TinyMCE has applied the class "mce-disabled" to the menuitem. Is this pointing to possibly something else in conflict and causing TinyMCE to disable are can I not apply a.* selectors?

I am using TinyMCE version 4

edit: CSS example

```
a.btn-standard {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e25200;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 1.25rem 2rem;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
```

How the menu item renders in tinymce

```
 <div id="mceu_94" class="mce-menu-item mce-menu-item-preview mce-stack-layout-item mce-disabled" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="true" aria-checked="false"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-none"></i>&nbsp;<span id="mceu_94-text" class="mce-text" style="font-family:&quot;Source Sans Pro&quot;, sans-serif;font-size:18.6667px;font-weight:600;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);text-transform:uppercase;color:rgb(255, 255, 255);background-color:rgb(226, 82, 0);padding:0 2px;border:0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);border-radius:0px;outline:rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;text-shadow:none;">a.btn-standard</span></div>
```

Comment: Could you share some of the CSS? I suspect this is an issue with [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:~:text=Specificity%20is%20an%20algorithm%20that,(or%20pseudo%2Delement).)

Comment: Edited with CSS

Comment: Can you create a TinyMCE Fiddle (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) that shows your complete configuration and this failure?  The issue is more likely in your TinyMCE configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure I can, I need to load a css file and a js file since i'm importing css functionality. I can say for certain there's something in conflict since it is disabled in tinymce and it's only the a. stuff

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. The selector is smart enough to require the  tag and  tag before allowing those formats to be selectable. The solution is to perform the steps of adding those elements first then the format is available as opposed to tinyMCE adding everything at once.